# Get Point from Another Table based on Category and Value Range

Tags: sql, mysql, join, range, between

I am trying to get a column which specify the points by comparing the value from original table to min and max value from another table. I have a main table, which consists of few columns of values and the respective point column to be inserted. Here is the example:

```
Main table
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User   | Department |  BU  |  Revenue | Revenuepoint | Profit |  Profitpoint |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| A      | 1000000    | 101  |  400     |              | 200    |              |
| B      | 1000001    | 101  |  300     |              | 100    |              |
| C      | 1000000    | 102  |  350     |              | 150    |              |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Point table
----------------------------------------------------------------
| Category| Department |  BU  |  Fromvalue  | Tovalue | Point  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| Revenue | 1000000    | 101  |  0          | 200     | 1      |
| Revenue | 1000000    | 101  |  201        | 400     | 2      |
| Revenue | 1000000    | 102  |  0          | 300     | 1      |
| Revenue | 1000000    | 102  |  301        | 400     | 2      |
| Revenue | 1000001    | 101  |  0          | 200     | 1      |
| Revenue | 1000001    | 101  |  201        | 400     | 2      |
| Profit  | 1000000    | 101  |  0          | 100     | 1      |
| Profit  | 1000000    | 101  |  101        | 300     | 2      |
| Profit  | 1000000    | 102  |  0          | 50      | 1      |
| Profit  | 1000000    | 102  |  51         | 200     | 2      |
| Profit  | 1000001    | 101  |  0          | 50      | 1      |
| Profit  | 1000001    | 101  |  51         | 200     | 2      |
----------------------------------------------------------------


Expected table
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User   | Department |  BU  |  Revenue | Revenuepoint | Profit |  Profitpoint |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| A      | 1000000    | 101  |  400     |       2      | 200    |       2      |
| B      | 1000001    | 101  |  300     |       2      | 40     |       1      |
| C      | 1000000    | 102  |  350     |       2      | 150    |       2      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Department and BU need to match and the RevenuePoint needs to take the records where the Category = Revenue, same as ProfitPoint.

I tried a few ways that i found in here, but most not as complex as mine so i have no idea how to move from here.

This is the code that i tried

```
SELECT 
a.User, 
a.Department, 
a.BU, 
a.Revenue, 
(SELECT MAX(b.Point) from Point b WHERE a.Revenue BETWEEN b.fromvalue and b.tovalue) as Revenuepoint,
b.Point as Revenuepoint,
a.Profit, 
(SELECT MAX(b.Point) from Point b WHERE a.Profit BETWEEN b.fromvalue and b.tovalue) as Profitpoint
FROM Sales a
```

Comment: Please update your question with the actual rules that need to be applied when matching records between the two tables. I'm assuming that the Department/BU need to match and that the Revenuepoint needs to just use records where the Category = Revenue (and similarly for the Profitpoint) - but you haven't actually stated any of these rules in your question and you shouldn't rely on people making correct assumptions when they are trying to help you

Comment: Hi - in your result you have ProfitPoint for user B  = 1. Shouldn't this be 2, as it will match the last record in your Points table? The profit amount in the main table is 100. Also, just as an aside, it makes it easier to help you if you ensure that the table column names you use for your data columns match the column names you use in your SQL e.g. "from" and "fromvalue"

Comment: Hi @NickW thank you for your comments. I have edited the post